# How to go through a dataframe and classify text either positive or negative?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, text-mining

I currently have a pandas dataframe which contains tokenized tweets.

I need to be able to go through each tweet and work out if it is positive or negative allowing me to add a subsequent column containing the word either positive or negative.

example data :

```
tokenized_tweets =  ['football, was, good, we, played, well' , 'We, were, unlucky, today, bad, luck' , 'terrible, performance, bad, game']
```

I need to be able to run a a loop through the tokenized_tweets section figuring out if it is positive or negative.

For the case of the examples, the positive and negative words are as followed:

```
Positive_words = ['good', 'great'] 
Negative_words = ['terrible, 'bad']
```

The desired output is a datafame which contains the tweet, how many positive letters each tweet contained, how many negative letters each tweet contained and if the tweet was positive, negative or neutral.

Postive negative and neutral needs to be worked out based upon whether a tweet has more positive or negative buzzwords

Desired output:

```
Tokenized tweet                    positive words       negative words         overall 
`football, was, good, we, played, well         1                0            positive` 

We, were, unlucky, today, bad, luck            0                1            negative
terrible, performance, bad, game               0                2            negative
```

Comment: You've described that algorithm you want.  There are many counting examples on line.  I don't see where you're stuck in a way that falls under the Stack Overflow mission.

Comment: i cant find that algorithm anywhere, the ones i can find are for lists and not a pandas dataframe, this causes an error. Also, the way in which i am stuck is the looping, i can count them easily, but looping through each record and counting each tweet individually is where the difficultly lies

Comment: Iterating through the records of a dataframe is covered well.  For the other part, you have ready access to a string containing words; you have a list of target words you want to count.  Again, where are you stuck?  It's sounding more an d more as if you need on-line tutorials or some human tutelage, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I understand that it needs to be an embedded for loop, one for going from word to word in the tokenized tweet section and the next to carry on to the next record once a record has been analysed for positive and negative words. I understand the theory being it, however when i implement it, it doesn't seem to work and errors always occur. The problem isn't the theory behind the code as such, yet is the implementation.

Comment: The place i am stuck is not the counting, it is the counting for each individual record compared to counting for the whole overall contents of the dataframe

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'tokenized_tweets': ['football, was, good, we, played, well', 'We, were, unlucky, today, bad, luck','terrible, performance, bad, game']})

Positive_words = ['good', 'great'] 
Negative_words = ['terrible','bad']

df['positive words'] = df['tokenized_tweets'].str.count('|'.join(Positive_words))
df['negative words'] = df['tokenized_tweets'].str.count('|'.join(Negative_words))

conditions = [
(df['positive words'] > df['negative words']),
(df['negative words'] > df['positive words']),
(df['negative words'] == df['positive words'])
]

choices = [
'positive',
'negative',
'neutral'
]

df['overall'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = '')

df
```

OUT:

```
tokenized_tweets                      positive words   negative words   overall
0   football, was, good, we, played, well   1               0        positive
1   We, were, unlucky, today, bad, luck     0               1        negative
2   terrible, performance, bad, game        0               2        negative
```

Comment: Add `df['tokenized_tweets'] = df['tokenized_tweets'].str.lower()` so case is not an issue